# Violation of UNIQUE KEY constraint Entity Framework

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, angular-material

So I have a select in my form that's getting the "categories" from my "records" from the DB correctly. The problem is that when I try to insert new data I get an error because EF is trying to create a new category with the same name instead of using an existing one, and the name has an unique constraint. Any ideas about how to get around this?

This is my form:

```
<mat-form-field appearance="fill">
  <mat-label>Category</mat-label>
  <mat-select name="category" #category="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="service.formData.category.name" >
    <mat-option  *ngFor="let category of categories | async " [value]="category.name">
      {{category.name}}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

This is the typescript:

```
export class BudgetFormComponent implements OnInit {
  categories : Observable<any>; 

  constructor(public service: BudgetService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.resetForm();
    this.categories = this.service.getCategories();
  }

  resetForm(form?: NgForm) {
    if (form != null)
      form.resetForm();

    this.service.formData = {
      id: 0,
      date: new Date,
      name: "",
      value: 0,
      categoryId: 0, 
      category: new Category(),
      type: ""
    }
  }

  onSubmit(form: NgForm) {
    console.log(form.value);
    if (this.service.formData.id == 0)
      this.insertRecord(form)
    else 
      this.updateRecord(form)
  }

  insertRecord(form: NgForm) {
    this.service.postRecordDetail().subscribe(
      res => {
        console.log("Insert ok")
        this.resetForm(form);
        this.service.getRecords();
      },
      err => {
        console.log(err);
      }
    );
  }
```

this is the post method in service

```
 export class BudgetService {
  formData: Record;
  ELEMENT_DATA: Record[] = []
  dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<Record>(this.ELEMENT_DATA);

  // readonly rootURL = 'https://boxestest.azurewebsites.net/api';
  readonly rootURL = 'https://localhost:5001/api'; 

  private fbSubs: Subscription[] = [];

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  postRecordDetail() {
    const httpOptions = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' })
    }
    return this.http.post(this.rootURL + '/records', this.formData, httpOptions)
  }
```

This is the controller (Asp.net Webapi)

```
    [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult<Record> AddRecord(Record record)
        {
            _context.Records.Add(record);
            _context.SaveChanges();

            return CreatedAtAction("GetRecordById", new { id = record.Id }, record);
        }
```

Comment: We need to see more code; start with the POST method, and the method which creates data in the database.

Comment: The frontend code wont likely be the problem here. Backend code which includes the models of EF and the service which you use to add the data in the backend would be useful

Answer (score 2):

Intially, the `Record record` entity is not being tracked by EF Core, neither is the `Category record.category` entity. After calling `_context.Records.Add(record)`, EF Core starts to track them and sets both entities to `Added`. Then, after calling `SaveChanges` both entities are added as new rows in the database.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult<Record> AddRecord(Record record)
{
    _context.Records.Add(record);
    // Category was not tracked initially. EF core starts to track it and SaveChanges will add a new row to the db
    _context.SaveChanges();

    return CreatedAtAction("GetRecordById", new { id = record.Id }, record);
}
```

There are several ways we could solve this.

**1)**

Add `_context.Entry(record.Category).State = EntityState.Unchanged;`. This tells EF core that the `Category` exists in the database and has not been changed.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult<Record> AddRecord(Record record)
{
    _context.Records.Add(record);
    _context.Entry(record.Category).State = EntityState.Unchanged;
    _context.SaveChanges();

    return CreatedAtAction("GetRecordById", new { id = record.Id }, record);
}
```

Our JSON data would look something like this (omitted some properties):

```
var raw = JSON.stringify({"id":0,"name":"R2","categoryId":1,"category":{"id":1,"name":"C1"}});
```

**2)**

We send only the data we need to create our new `Record`.

Remove `category` from our JSON data and use only the `categoryId` to define which `Category` we want on the `Record`:

```
var raw = JSON.stringify({"id":0,"name":"R3","categoryId":1});
```

The POST method would not change:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult<Record> AddRecord(Record record)
{
    _context.Records.Add(record);
    _context.SaveChanges();

    return CreatedAtAction("GetRecordById", new { id = record.Id }, record);
}
```